# Problema al instalar pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

tengo **numpy** instalado en mi sistema `ubuntu`, lo puedo comprobar asi:

`$ pip show numpy`

Con lo que obtengo

```
Name: numpy
Version: 1.17.4
Summary: NumPy is the fundamental package for array computing with Python.
Home-page: https://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /home/alejandro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
```

Para instalar pandas me descargo el .whl porque mi conexión es mala y cuando hago

`$ pip install pandas-0.25.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl`

Me dice que no encuentra una versión de numpy correcta

> none Processing ./pandas-0.25.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
>   Collecting numpy>=1.13.3 (from pandas==0.25.3)   Could not find a
>   version that satisfies the requirement numpy>=1.13.3 (from
>   pandas==0.25.3) (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for
>   numpy>=1.13.3 (from pandas==0.25.3)

Que puede estar pasando? Gracias de antemano

Comment: descarga tambien el `whl` de numpy e instalalo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fíjate de instalar pandas con pip3, ya que la location que pones para numpy es:

```
Location: /home/alejandro/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

Dejanos saber si era ese el error.Saludos.

Comment: Ese no es el problema, yo tengo un alias creado de modo que cuando uso pip mi sistema usa pip3 por defecto. De todos modos ya lo pude instalar, desintalé los paquetes y empecé de nuevo, (Como me enseñaron en la universidad, jejeje) y todo fue bien. Mil gracias de todas formas, estoy seguro que la respuesta será válida para alguien más.